# Session expiration attribute doesn't get fired at the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session-variables, actionfilterattribute

I'm trying to track session expiration and everything works fine when the application is running on my development PC. but It doesn't work on the live server as expected. I already restart the server but no luck! I'm running on windows server 2012 (windows azure vm) and IIS 8.

I'm receiving a similar error based on controller whose action is fired. Error is generated because the controller is failed to initialize as the session variable _connectionstring is null when the session is expired.

If I changed the sessionState to 1 and form timeout to 2 and then the redirection worked perfectly in the both server and development environments. Strange!!

My question is why the action filter is miss behaving on the live server environment? It works perfectly fine under development environment. what do I missing here?

Following is my code.

Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Auth/Login" timeout="25" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Filter Config:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new SessionExpireFilterAttribute());
        filters.Add(new LocsAuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Filters:

```
public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipActionFilterAttribute), false).Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        HttpContextBase ctx = filterContext.HttpContext;
        //HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check if session is supported
        if (ctx.Session != null)
        {
            // check if a new session id was generated
            if (ctx.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                // If it says it is a new session, but an existing cookie exists, then it must
                // have timed out
                string sessionCookie = ctx.Request.Headers["Cookie"];
                if ((null != sessionCookie) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))
                {
                    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                    {
                        // For AJAX requests, we're overriding the returned JSON result with a simple string,
                        // indicating to the calling JavaScript code that a redirect should be performed.
                        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "_Logon_" };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                            new RouteValueDictionary {
                            { "action", "SessionTimeout" },
                            { "controller", "Session" }});
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}

//[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class LocsAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipActionFilterAttribute), false).Any())
        {
            return;
        }
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // If the browser session has expired...
        if (ctx.Session["UserName"] == null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                // For AJAX requests, we're overriding the returned JSON result with a simple string,
                // indicating to the calling JavaScript code that a redirect should be performed.
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult { Data = "_Logon_" };
            }
            else
            {
                // For round-trip posts, we're forcing a redirect to Home/TimeoutRedirect/, which
                // simply displays a temporary 5 second notification that they have timed out, and
                // will, in turn, redirect to the logon page.
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                            { "action", "SessionTimeout" },
                            { "controller", "Session" }});
            }
        }
        else if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Otherwise the reason we got here was because the user didn't have access rights to the
            // operation, and a 403 should be returned.
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}

public class SkipActionFilterAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that the you are using the visual studio development server locally and IIS on the server. I'm going to guess that this pattern of Session usage depends on the pipeline order of events and the Session doesn't exsit yet when IIS does it because IIS by default is in Integrated mode. Try changing to Classic, or change how you use Session so that it works with Integrated.

Comment: Also I think someone down voted you because this is a little too much code for the question.

Comment: Yes, I'm running on VS 2013 dev server locally. What did you mean by "Session doesn't exists yet"? Application is running smoothly till the session expiration. Also it runs properly on the server when I set a very short session timeout such as 1 or 2. But if I leave the web page for more than 30 mins, action attribute no longer fires.

Comment: Aside from that, just load the connection string and don't send it through session at all. You are stuffing it a static variable that will load once and exist for the life of the appdomain. I understand this won't help for other uses of Session, but for connection string it doesn't make sense. Session is for volatile user data that you need to go away from time to time. something like static constring=ConfiugrationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however connection string can be changed based on the user or session. i.e. I use multiple databases within the application. i.e. all the users are provided with an option to select the database at the time of login.FYI: I tried running the app on classic mode, but I'm getting the same behavior. i.e. filter doesn't work and ended up with NullReferenceException.

Comment: That connection string would have had to have come from somewhere before you put it in session, refetch it.  Your next step is to get IIS Express on your machine and debug while running real IIS, or less pleasantly, trying to attach a remote debugger or install VS on the server. Or post a different question where you ask *only* about how to use session on IIS in  the context of an MVC filter/attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the reason for the misbehavior.

My action filter doesn't fire as IIS > Application Pools > Advance Settings> idle timeout (minutes) setting reaches the timeout before my session state. Default value is 20.

Setting the value to 0 will disable the IIS idel timeout.

Answer (score 0):

it will give the error

Error: Invalid value for the Session timeout parameter. Enter a positive integer number less than or equal to 500000.

you can try

```
if ((Session["project"] == null) && (Session["User"] == null) && (Label1.Text == "Label") && (Label2.Text == "Label"))

    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }

    else
    {

        if ((Session["User"] == null) || (Session["project"] == null))

        {
            Session["project"] = Label1.Text;
            Session["User"] = Label2.Text;
        }

        if ((Label1.Text == "Label") || (Label2.Text == "Label"))

        {
            Label1.Text = Session["project"].ToString();
            Label2.Text = Session["User"].ToString();
        }

    }
```

And Make you authentication mode is None instead of Window from your IIS> Asp.net setting > Authentication mode